# SQLite : Pragma cache_spill = false not working

Tags: sqlite, pragma

I was getting a "database locked" error while reading as I was executing long transaction. Since Cache_Spill is the reason for this exclusive lock, I wanted to avoid exclusive lock on the database . So I needed to set cache_spill = false.

But the following code seems not to be working.

```
iretval = sqlite3_exec(pSqlHandle,
            "PRAGMA cache_spill=false",ZERO,ZERO,ZERO);
    if(iretval != SQLITE_OK)
    {
        iretval = DB_QUERY_FAILED;
        goto db_close;
    }
```

I am not getting any error.But I am still getting the lock at the same position while reading.

**EDIT**

Just to check, I intentionally mistyped as `PRAGMA cahe_spill=false` and I didn't get any error. So the first question is, am I executing the pragma correctly?

**EDIT**
I am executing it after opening the database.

Answer (score 0):

Unknown PRAGMAs are ignored.
(PRAGMA cache_spill was introduced in SQLite 3.8.0.)

You cannot prevent writing to disk when SQLite runs out of memory in its page cache; PRAGMA cache_spill prevents only write before that.
You also have to increate the [page cache size](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_cache_size).

Comment: I didn't get it , "You cannot prevent writing to disk when SQLite runs out of memory in its page cache". Does that mean that SQLite will acquire EXCLUSIVE lock even after setting `cache_spill=false` ? I was thinking that if I set it to false, then SQLite will acquire more memory for itself to fit changes and if still it runs out of memory OS will take care of that. (Anyways, my MAX DB size is 10MB)

Comment: What else should it do? Abort with "out of memory"?

Comment: So I need both `cache_spill` and `cache_size` , right? In that case when should I set them? before opening the database or after?

Comment: You cannot execute anything without a database.